# Using cascadeType.Merge duplicates my entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

I have an entity "Employee" and a @Embeddable class RecycleBin. Now whenever a user deletes anything in the system the the entity class record is duplicated. I know it is because of the cascadeType.Merge i added in the RecycleBin class but if I remove cascadeType.Merge then the system crashes on delete operation giving a server error of "save transient before flushing". I have been stuck in this since two days and i am new to spring. If someone could please help me.

This is my Employee class.

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Version
private Long version;

private String fullName;

private String fatherName;

private String identityCardNo;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dateOfBirth;

private String placeOfBirth;

private String nationality;

private String email;

private String phoneNumber;

@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String permanentResAddr;

@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String presentResAddr;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private MaritalStatus martialStatus;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Gender gender;

private String spouseName;

private String spouseOccupation;

private String spouseOrganization;

private String spouseDesignation;

private String numOfDependents;

private String languagesKnown;


private String salary;
private String bonus;
private String allowance;
private String stipend;


@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Column(name = "jobrole")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private List<JobRole> jobRoles;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private JobType jobType;

@ElementCollection(targetClass = Privilege.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Column(name = "privilege")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private List<Privilege> privileges;

// dep auto del
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "substituteTeacher")
private List<TimetableSubstitute> timetableSubstitutes;

// dep manul del
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "createdBy")
private List<SchemeOfWork> createdSchemeOfWorks;

// dep association del
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "createdBy")
private List<CommentBank> createdComments;

// dep manul del
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "teacher")
private List<BatchSubject> teacherSubjects;

// dep auto del
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "employee_campus", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "employee", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "branch", referencedColumnName = "id") })
private List<Campus> schoolCampuses;

// dep auto del
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
private List<CampusEmployeeAttendance> employeeBranchAttendanceList;

// dep auto del
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
private List<EmployeeAttendance> employeeDayAttendanceList;

// dep association del
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "createdByTeacher")
private List<ProfileForm> teacherCreateProfileForms;

// dep auto del
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "employees")
private List<Announcement> announcements;

// dep auto del
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
private List<Notification> notification;

// dep auto del
@OneToOne
private UserLoginAccount employeeLoginAccount;

// dep manul del
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "batchTeacher")
private List<Batch> teacherBatches;

// dep manul del
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "schoolEmployee")
private Parent parent;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@CollectionTable(name = "employee_qualifications", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "emp", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<Qualification> qualifications;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@CollectionTable(name = "employee_pre_employment", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "emp", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<PreEmployment> preEmployments;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@CollectionTable(name = "employee_memberships", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "emp", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<EmpMembership> memberships;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@CollectionTable(name = "employee_certificates", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "emp", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<EmpCertificate> certificates;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@CollectionTable(name = "employee_references", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "emp", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<EmpReference> references;

// dep auto del
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<FileLibrary> empImages;

@Embedded
private RecycleBin recycleBin;
```

And this is my RecycleBin class.

```
@Embeddable
public class RecycleBin {

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date deleteDate;

@ManyToOne(cascade= CascadeType.MERGE)
private Employee deletedBy;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private RecycleBinStatus recycleBinStatus;
```

Comment: Use `cascadeType.ALL`

Comment: I have tried that too. But it did not help me.